# Rotating a child shape relative to its parent's orientation

Tags: 3d, mathematics, matrix, rotation, quaternion

When rotating a shape using a quaternion value I also wish rotate its child shape.

The parent and child shapes both start with different orientations but their relative orientations should always be the same.

How can I use the difference between the previous and current quaternions of the parent shape in order to transform the child segment and rotate it relative to its parent shape?

```
    public Quaternion Orientation
    {
        get { return entity.Orientation; }
        set
        {
            Quaternion previousValue = entity.Orientation;
            entity.Orientation = value;

            // Use the difference between the quaternion values to update child orientation
        }
    }
```

EDIT:

If I have understood `teodron` correctly then this is what I must do

```
// Qc' = Qp' * Inv(Qp) * Qc
//
// Where:
// Qp   = Parent orientation last frame
// Qp'  = Parent orientation this frame
// Qc   = Child orientation last frame
// Qc'  = Child orientation this frame

set
{
    Quaternion previousValue = entity.Orientation;

    entity.Orientation = value;

    Quaternion childOrienation = value * Quaternion.Inverse(previousValue) * childOrientationPrev;
    //Quaternion childOrienation = childOrientationPrev * Quaternion.Inverse(previousValue) * value;
}
```

I have tried both multiplication orders but neither method rotates the child object correctly and instead it spins very quickly.

Comment: do you somehow synchronize the `previousOrientation/value` in another method in your code? Try making those values fixed (i.e. as if they describe the object at start-up). If it doesn't work, let me know, I'll try to code them myself and get back to you with a verified concept (it might not be C#, but pseudocode since I do not use C# libraries for quat math and rendering).

Comment: The only place the orientation is ever changed is via the `Orientation` property using the `set` method.  There is currently nowhere else in the code that changes the orientation outside this method.

Comment: so `previousValue` is not tampered with after its creation? In this case, I'll try shortly to update the answer with a working, tested, pseudocoded solution.

Comment: _so previousValue is not tampered with after its creation?_  That is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just store the static orientation difference between parent and child once at startup, lets call it qDiff.

Whenever you set the new parent orientation, set child's orientation like this:

```
qChild = qNewParentOrientation * qDiff
```

Comment: This sounds like a very good idea.  I shall implement it after returning from work.

Comment: How do I calculate the orientation difference between the parent and child object?

Comment: `qDiff = conjugate(qParent) * qChild`

Comment: It is like @MaikSemder suggests: your code snippet seems to be mathematically correct. Your update equation is: `Qc = Qp * conj(Qp0) * Qc0`. Maik suggests you do: `Qc = Qp * dQ`, meaning `Qc = Qp * conj(Qp0) * Qc`. Again, if your `dQ` quotient quaternion (difference sounds odd in a multiplicative field ;) ) is not changing, the maths are completely right.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

Tested and confirmed to work:

Say you have two objects: a *source* and a *target* object.

The target must keep a certain relative orientation with respect to a source object.
This is really the case with most fundamental camera tracking scenarios (e.g. camera behind a flying entity - plane, spaceship, etc.).

If a given reference pose of this binary system is given, say at start-up, then we must grab hold on the orientations of the source and target objects:

- **Qtgt0** = the quaternion describing how the frame of the target relates to the world frame
- **Qsrc0** = the quaternion describing how the frame of the source object relates to the world frame

The 0 suffix denotes the initial state. These two quats shouldn't change from now on, they remain untouched. The *relative* orientation of a target with respect to a source is
**not** the difference of the quaternions, but this guy: **Qsrc0.inverse** * **Qtgt0** (something similar to a division operator for quaternions - but since the quaternion multiplication does not commute, such an operator is "left or right handed").

At a certain time instance, the source has the **Qsrc** orientation. To couple the orientation of the target to that of the source, *set* the orientation of the target to be:

**Qtgt** = **Qsrc** * **Qrelative** = **Qsrc** * **Qsrc0.inverse** * **Qtgt0**

The picture below illustrates an experiment where a cube gets the camera's quat and a 
parabolic tube springing from one of the cube's faces rotates with the cube **although** they are *not* attached to the same scene node, nor is the cube's node a child of the cube's node (talking hierarchical node transformations in a scene graph). Both objects are linked to the world independently, but when the scene is created, their relative orientation is stored separately for future updates.

### [image]

*An example:*

Say you have a *ship* and a *camera* object in a simple scene.

Let **Qs** be the ship's current quat and **Qc** the camera's current quaternion. Let this configuration **Qs,Qc** be the initial, reference position you are talking about.

If the ship changes its orientation from **Qs** to **Qs'**, then you could write:

**Qs'** = **Qs'** * **inv(Qs)** * **Qs**

**Qs'** * **Qs** is a *relative* rotation transformation. If you apply it to the camera's 
initial orientation, you get a new camera orientation that should be in tune to your ship's change in orientation, as desired. The **inv(Qs)** factor tells us that there is an intricate orientation coupling that is initially set, between our camera and ship objects.

**inv(q)** denotes the inverse of a quat, which is the same as its conjugate **q*** if the quat is normalized.

Further explanation:

To get a result, the camera's orientation, when the ship changes heading, should look like:

**Qc'** = **Qs'** * **inv(Qs)** * **Qc**

Be aware that the ***_*** operator is the quaternion multiplication. When rotating vectors, you will multiply the orientation quat **q** with (0,_v_) and then right multiply it by **q**.

Comment: I have studied your answer but I cannot get it to work correctly.  I've edited the original question to show how I am using your advice in code form.  However, it is not working for me and the object spins very quickly rather than rotating slowly.